# Что такое неслоговые гласные?

Tags: фонетика, терминология

Возник спор, насколько правильно выражение "неслоговые гласные буквы". Разрешите его, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке большинство гласных слоговые; можно лишь отметить, что в некоторых случаях мы сталкиваемся с *и неслоговым*, обнаруживаемым при произнесении слов, в написании который в конце стоит и краткое: *сини**й**, зелены**й**, мечто**й***. *И неслоговое* также называют *полугласным*: он отличается от согласного [j] (произносится короче и с меньшим нажимом) и от гласного (не образует слога; поэтому и называется *неслоговым*).

Другое дело, что, в общем, гласных **букв** не бывает (а тем более — неслоговых); бывают гласные ***звуки***. Буква — значок, используемый для письма, звук — то, что произносится.

Так, "неслоговые гласные буквы" некорректно, правильно: неслоговые гласные **звуки**.